# Entropy of $Binomial(n, 1-2^{-1/n})$

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory, binomial-distribution, entropy

I am interested in the entropy of the binomial random variable $Binom(n,1-2^{-1/n})$.

Specifically,  I would like to show that this is an increasing function in $n$.?

I was able to verify this through numerical simulation. Also, if the probability parameter was a constant (not a function of $n$) it is known to be an increasing function in $n$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4325748/is-entropy-of-a-binomial-distribution-an-increasing-function-of-n).

Can someone help me prove this property.

**My attempt:**

From [this paper](http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/harremoes-binomial.pdf), we know that entropy of $Binom(n,\lambda/n)$ is an increasing function in $n$.

Also, entropy of $Binom(n,p)$ is maximum when $p=1/2$.

For large values of $n$,  $Binom(n,1-2^{-1/n})=Binom(n,\frac{\ln 2}{n})$. Thus, once $n$ is large enough, entropy of $Binom(n,1-2^{-1/n})$ is increasing function in $n$.

But  I am still not sure how to establish the conjecture for low values of $n$. Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: I added a  partial solution in "my attempt". Can someone help me complete this?