# Entropy of the multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, closed-form, information-theory, entropy, multinomial-distribution

What is the entropy of the multinomial distribution? To fix notation, let us define $n > 0$ as the number of trials, $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ as the probabilities of each of the $k$ possible outcomes and $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ as the outcomes. Recall that the pmf of the multinomial distribution is given by

$f(x; n,p) \equiv f(x_1,\ldots, x_k; n, p_1, \ldots, p_k) = \cases{ \frac{n!}{x_1! \ldots x_k!} p_1^{x_1} \ldots p_k^{x_k} \hspace{1cm} \text{if }\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i = 1 \\ 0 \hspace{4cm} \text{otherwise} }$

The (Shannon) entropy of a distribution measures the amount of stored information or the uncertainty and for this distribution takes the form

$H = - \sum f(x; n,p) \log{f(x; n,p)} = E[-\log{f(x; n,p)}]$,

where the sum is over all $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = n$.

The entropy for the binomial distribution can be calculated (see linked question). However, for the multinomial distribution it has only been shown that the entropy is maximized when $p_i = \frac{1}{k}$ for all $i$ [1, 2]. There is a recent paper [[3](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7282678/)] which sets upper and lower bounds on the entropy. However, a closed-form expression for the entropy seems not to have been derived yet.

**My questions are:
(A) Is there a closed form for the special case  $p_i = \frac{1}{k} \hspace{0.5cm} \forall i$ ?
(B) Are there other special cases for which the entropy can be calculated? 
(C) Why is it so difficult to obtain a closed-form solution for this?**

**Linked questions**

[Entropy of a binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244455/entropy-of-a-binomial-distribution)

**References**

[[1](https://statistics.stanford.edu/research/entropy-sum-independent-bernoulli-random-variables-and-multinomial-distribution)]: P. Mateev, On the entropy of a multinomial distribution, Teor.
Veroyatnost. i Primenen., 1978, Volume 23, Issue 1, 196–198, [link](https://statistics.stanford.edu/research/entropy-sum-independent-bernoulli-random-variables-and-multinomial-distribution).

[[2](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1123020.)]: L.A. Shepp, I. Olkin, Entropy of the Sum of Independent Bernoulli Random Variables and of the Multinomial Distribution, Technical Report, 1978, [link](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1123020.).

[[3](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7282678/)]: Yuichi Kaji, Bounds on the entropy of multinomial distribution, 2015 IEEE International Symposium on Information Theory (ISIT), [link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7282678/).

Comment: for $p_i=1/k=constant$ the sum is trivial,right?

Comment: Sorry I had some mistakes in the definitions. Corrected now.

Comment: If people went to ISIT as recently as 2015 with just bounds then I doubt this is answerable.

Comment: You can check this answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207893/entropy-of-the-multinomial-distribution).