# entropy of the sum of binomial distributions

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution, entropy

Suppose that one has $X_1 \sim Bin(n,p)$ and $X_2 \sim Bin(n,1-p)$ and that $Z$ is distributed s.t:

$$
P(Z = k) = .5 P(X_1=k) + .5P(X_2=k)
$$

How do we compute the entropy? For a binomial distributed variable i have seen this proof:

[Entropy of a binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244455/entropy-of-a-binomial-distribution)

let $A = p^k (1-p)^{n-k} + (1-p)^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ then we see that:

\begin{align}
H(Z) &= -.5 \sum {n \choose k} \Big[A\Big] \log \Big[.5{n \choose k}A\Big] \\&= 1 - .5\sum {n \choose k} \Big[A\Big] \log \Big[{n \choose k}\Big] -  .5\sum {n \choose k} \Big[A\Big] \log \Big[A\Big]
\end{align}

Using de-Moivre-Laplace theorem, i get:

\begin{align*}
1+\log_2(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma) + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big[e^{{\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2})}}+e^{{\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2})}}\Big] \log_2(e^{{\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2})}}+e^{{\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2})}})
\end{align*}

where $\mu_1 = np, \mu2 = n(1-p)$ and $\sigma^2 = np(1-p)$
I tried to get the integral on the right hand side using Mathematica but that failed. Any suggestions on how to get the exact or approximation of this integral? What i tried is this:

\begin{align*}
R &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}\Big[e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}}+e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Big]\log_2\left(e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}}+e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}\Big[e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}}+e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Big]\Big[\log_2\left(e^{\frac{(x-\mu_{1})^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)+\log_2\left(1+e^{\frac{-(2p-1)(n-2x)}{2(p-1)p}}\right)\Big]
\\& \approx \frac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big[e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}}+e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Big]\log_2\left(\left(e^{\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\right) + \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_\frac{n}{2}^{\infty}\left(e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}}+e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) e^{\frac{-(2p-1)(n-2x)}{2(p-1)p}} \\&= \frac{1}{4}\log_2(e)\left(1 + (\sigma^2 + (n-2\mu_1)^2)\right) + \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_\frac{n}{2}^{\infty}\left(e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}}+e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) e^{\frac{-(2p-1)(n-2x)}{2(p-1)p}}
\end{align*}

The approximation

$\log_2(1+e^{\frac{-(2p-1)(n-2x)}{2(p-1)p}}) \approx e^{\frac{-(2p-1)(n-2x)}{2(p-1)p}} \text{if } x \in [\frac{n}{2},\infty)$ and since the function is symetrical around $\frac{n}{2}$ i can just multiply the integration by 2. The right hand side gives me an ugly term so i was wondering if an approximation there could work?

Are there more theorems that i should consider looking at?

Comment: The entropy will vary between $H_0$ and $H_0+1$, where $H_0$ is the entropy of a single binomial. (For $p=0.5$ you're just reproducing the binomial, and for $p\to0$ you have one extra bit of information for which branch was used.) So you could try to subtract out the $H_0$ part and approximate the rest as a function between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: How did you come up with these bounds? I do understand it has an upper bound of 1 and lower bound of 0, is that what you mean?

Comment: What are you referring to by "it"?

Comment: the entropy but you clarified everything in your answer thanks :D

Comment: I didn't write an answer; it's by leonbloy.

Answer (score 2):

For small $n$, you just compute it numerically.

If you need an approximation for large $n$, (and $p$ not too close to $0$ or $1$) you can rely on the approximation for a single Binomial distribution from the linked question:

$$H(B;n,p)=\frac1 2 \log_2 \big( 2\pi e\, np(1-p) \big) + O \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \tag{1}$$

You can combine this with the known expression for the entropy of a mixture: Let $Z$ be a rv chosen from one of two rvs $X,Y$ with probabilities $\alpha,1-\alpha$; then, applying the entropy chain rule to $H(Z,A)$ (where $A$ is a variable that indicates which of the two rvs was chose) we get

$$H(Z)=H(A)+H(Z\mid A) - H(A\mid Z)=h(\alpha)+\alpha H(X) + (1-\alpha)H(Y)- H(A\mid Z) \tag{2}$$

where $h(\cdot)$ is the binary entropy function. In our case, $\alpha=\frac12$ and $H(X)=H(Y)=H(B;n,p)$, hence

$$H(Z)=1 + H(B;n,p) - H(A \mid Z) \tag{3}$$

Because $0\le H(A \mid Z)\le1$,

$$H(B;n,p)\le H(Z)\le 1 + H(B;n,p) $$
Assuming $0<p<1$ and $n\to \infty$, then $$ H(Z) =
 \frac1 2 \log_2 \big( 2\pi e\, np(1-p) \big) + O(1)\\
\approx \frac1 2 \log_2 \big( 2\pi e\, np(1-p) \big)$$

Comment: I really like the way of thinking in this proof, do you think for small $n$ only numerical approximations are possible?

Comment: For small $n$, one can hardly think of something better than just computing it numerically  - even the entropy of a single Binomial